# (MatLab) Problem is unbounded when doing the linear programming in matlab

Tags: linear-programming, matlab

```
x + y ≤ 44,
2x + y ≤ 64,
9,000x + 5,000y ≤ 300,000
```

**objective function**: `30,000x + 20,000y`

I would like to find the Optimal solution in **Matlab**

But there are error message `Problem is unbounded.`

Here is my code

```
A = [1 1;2 1;9 5];

b = [44 64 300];

f = [3 2];

x = linprog(f,A,b)
```

suppose ans: `x=20,y=24`

**Reference**
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**linprog** solve minimization problems.

Citing the linked reference

> Reference https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html

Linear programming solver.

Finds the minimum of a problem specified by:

\begin{equation}
\min_x f^Tx \quad \text{such that} 
\begin{cases}
A \cdot x \le b, \\
Aeq \cdot x = beq, \\
lb \le x \le ub
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $f$, $x$, $b$, $beq$, $lb$, and $ub$ are vectors, and $A$ and $Aeq$ are matrices.

Since you do not specify the boundaries for the variables $x$ and $y$ (for example you add $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$) and the constraint gives only an upper bound the minimization problem is unbounded.

In order to maximize the objective function using **linprog** you have to change the problem into an equivalent minimization problem.

The simplest solution is to multiply the objective function by -1.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It is useful that I know how to solve the problem